# When are extensions of algebraically good groups algebraically good?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gr.group-theory, homological-algebra

Let $G$ be a discrete group. The *pro-algebraic completion* of $G$ is a pro-algebraic group $G^{\mathrm{alg}}$ together with a morphism $s:G\to G^{\mathrm{alg}}$ which is initial among all morphisms from $G$ to a  pro-algebraic group.

A discrete group $G$ is *algebraically good* if for any positive integer $n$ and any finite dimensional $G$-representation $V$ the canonical induced morphism
$$
s^{*}:H^{n}(G^{\mathrm{alg}},V)\to H^{n}(G,V)
$$ 
is an isomorphism.

**Question 1:** If we have a short exact sequence of discrete groups 
$$
1\to N\to G\to H\to 1,
$$
with $N$ and $H$ both algebraically good, when can we conclude that $G$ is algebraically good?

The only result of this type that I know is that when all three groups are assumed to be finitely generated and type $F$, then an extension of an algebraically good group by a free group is algebraically good.

**Question 2:** Does anyone know of an example of an extension of algebraically good groups which is not algebraically good?

**Question 3:** Is the pro-algebraic completion functor exact?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what is an example of a group that is not algebraically good?

Comment: Completion is not exact, because of the fact that $k$-sheeted cover of $SP(n, \Bbb Z)$ is not residually finite. Intersection of finite index subgroups is precisely that central subgroup that will be killed by any f. d. rep, and completion of finite group is the group itself as discrete scheme. However, in characteristic zero finite cyclic groups are acyclic, so that doesn't help with first two questions.